# Webmatrix - URL rewrite module

Tags: iis, url-rewriting, webmatrix, iis-express

Does anyone have any experience with creating URL rewrites in `Webmatrix`? Because it uses `IIS Express` instead of `IIS 7`, there's nowhere for me to create these rules.

I am deploying to `IIS 7` on my production server, so if I need to do any rewrites, I need to make them directly in production to test.

Is there any way I can switch to using `IIS` instead of `IIS Express` on my local machine?

I have tried a few things to get local `IIS` working, but to no avail.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can install IIS on a Windows 7 or Windows 8 machine by going to Control Panel -> Programs and Features -> Turn Windows features on or off. Make sure to install enough of the components to get a WebMatrix site working - ASP.NET & the management console for certain.

You can then create a virtual server for the directory your project is in and use the IIS management console to play around with URL rewriting. You may need to install the UrlRewrite module using the MS Web Platform Installer, available here:

http://www.microsoft.com/web/downloads/platform.aspx

If you need more help getting your local IIS working, give me some more information on how far you've got and I'll try and extend my answer.

Comment: Thanks Polly, my site was actually hosted on a dropbox folder, so had to add permissions for IIS_IUSR to get it to work, but all working now. Thanks